# How would I access my toString() method in a ChangeListener in my Composite JButton class?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jbutton

I have a JButton composition class and I have a toString I am sending to a JLabel in a different class. When I call the toString I'm getting something like: javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel@f730d2f

```
public class EmptySpace{

  private JButton button;
  protected int x; 
  protected int y;
  protected String name;

  public EmptySpace(String text, int x, int y){
    this.name = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    button = new JButton(text);
    button.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
            if (model.isRollover()) {
                Board.toStringText.setText(e.getSource().toString()); //Where toString is called
            } else if (model.isPressed()) {

            }  
        }
    });

  }

  public String toString(){ //toString I want to access
      return "Name: " + name + " Xcoords: " + x + " Ycoords: " + y;

  }

  public JButton getButton(){
      return button;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EmptySpace.this.toString()`.